# Are those magnetic iron filings in the dirt pure iron?

Tags: iron, composition

When I was a kid we used to drag magnets around in the dirt and collect "iron filings". Are they pure iron, or something else?

Comment: How in the world would anyone be able to know? There are many different sorts of dirt out there, after all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we just don't know.

Comment: Metallic iron deposits are exceptionally rare in the natural environment.  The filings were almost certainly not iron, unless they were scraps or powders from human-based industrial operations.

Comment: The earth surface is littered* with rust particles, mostly from human sources. $\ce{Fe2O3}$  is magnetic.

Answer (score 4):

More likely they were iron oxides. In moist soil ,iron/steel filings would not last more than a few weeks before turning to oxides. Now the "oxides" are not simply Fe O, Fe 2 O 3, Fe 3 O 4 , they are also hydrates, hydroxides ,etc.

Comment: Then again, not all oxides and hydroxides are magnetic.

Comment: Agreed, i type slow and did not put in that qualification.